# "Fail to decode font from..." error when using react-web-vector-icons in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, icons, gatsby

Trying to use react-web-vector-icon library within a Gatsby site.  I've followed all docs to properly install, import, and require in all the right places, but I still only get a box to show up where the icon should be.

In my index.js file:
`require('react-web-vector-icons/fonts');`

In my index.html file, within the head tag:
`<style> @font-face{font-family:MaterialCommunityIcons;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf) format('truetype')}</style>`

In my component that is using the icon:

```
import Icon, { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "react-web-vector-icons";

...

<MaterialCommunityIcons
    name='cart-outline'
    color='black'
    size={60}
/>

<Icon
    name='cart-outline'
    font='MaterialCommunityIcons'
    color='black'
    size={30}
/>
```

I've even tried using the react-helmet plugin too thinking the problem was that the style tag was getting eliminated from html file with each build.  For that part I installed the plugin, and added the following to my files:

In my index.js:

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

...

//created a class component to render the helmet...

render() {
    return(
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <style> @font-face{font-family:MaterialCommunityIcons;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf) format('truetype')}</style>
            </Helmet>

...
```

And added the plugin to the gatsby-config.js file:
`` plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`] ``

I've tried adding the plugin to the module.exports object in that file, and tried it outside.  Nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a work around... I used

`npm install react-icons`

then in the component I wanted to use an icon I

`import { IconName } from 'react-icons/fa'`

then where I wanted to use the icon I just called it directly

`<IconName />`

and it worked :-)